# How to change Plotly subplots shared range Selector position

Tags: python, plotly

In Plotly, if I add a shared range selector to plot with multiple subplots, it will be misplaced in the middle between the two subplots.
[you can see the plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYMsE.png)

How can I place the range selector in the bottom of the plot.

Below is the code to generate the plot.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly import graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Low)), row=2, col=1)


fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair`rangeslider` with bottom most x-axis and `rangeselector` with top most x-axis

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv"
)

df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

fig = make_subplots(2, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Low)), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list(
                [
                    dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                    dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all"),
                ]
            )
        ),
        type="date",
    ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        rangeslider=dict(visible=True),
        type="date",
    ),
)
fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
fig
```